Cascade delete issue with JPA for related entities in Spring Boot
I am working with the following entity relationships:
Color Entity:
 @Entity
public class Color  {
 
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "color",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Car> cars ;

Car Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car  {
   
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
     private Brand brand;
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
     cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
             CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.REFRESH
     })
@JoinColumn(name = "color_id")
    private Color color;

Brand  Enity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "brand")
public class Brand {
  
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "brand",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Car> cars ;

A Car entity is related to Brand and Color entities.
Repository Class:
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car,Integer> {
}

ServiceImpl Class:
@Service
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
    private CarRepository carRepository;
    @Autowired
    public CarServiceImpl(CarRepository carRepository){
        this.carRepository=carRepository;

    }
    @Override
@Transactional
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        Car car = carRepository.findById(theId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Car not found"));
        carRepository.delete(car);

    }  
}

Main Code:
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(CarService carService, BrandService brandService, ColorService colorService,
                                               AdService adService){
        return runner->{
            brandService.deleteById(1);
        };
        }

If I delete a Car, its related Brand and Color entities should not be deleted.
However, if a related Brand or Color is deleted, the corresponding Car should also be deleted.
Additionally, the Car entity is linked to an Advertisement table.
When I try to delete a Car entity using the deleteById(int id) method from JPA, the entity is not being removed from the database.
On the other hand, when I try to delete a Brand entity, I encounter the following error:
Iorg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: persistent instance references an unsaved transient instance of 'com.emin.nereye.entity.Brand' (save the transient instance before flushing
    

How can I configure my entities and cascading rules to achieve the desired behavior? Any help would be appreciated!
